# python POST request getting hit twice

Tags: python, html, wsgi

I am doing wsgi python and calling aws workspaces api to get all the workspaces and render on the screen (webpage). But I see my logs, that the function is getting called twice just by hitting the index URL.

#### server side

```
ws_butt='get'
request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)
d = parse_qs(request_body)
ws_butt=d.get('ws_butt',['get'])[0]

if ws_butt.lower()=='get':
          #calls describe_workspaces to fetch all the workspaces for the user
          new_content=[]
          for region,endpoint in region_endpoint_dict.iteritems():
              code,content=describe_workspaces(region,endpoint[0],session_username=username)
              #some processing on content and generate new_content
          if new_content:
               #some internal processing of replacing strings
               return your_workspace_window(environ, start_response,my_response=new_content)
```

#### client side

```
start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
html_output='''
<html>
   <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
                    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
                    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

   </head>
   <body>

    <form id="form_myws" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="workspaceid" value="%s">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="%s">
    <input type="hidden" name="region" value="%s">
    <input type="hidden" name="state" value="%s">
    <input type="hidden" name="ipaddress" value="%s">
    <p><center><input type="submit" value="Reboot" name="ws_butt" id="submit" class="submit"/></center></p>
    </body>
    '''
    #some more processing on client side
```

What is causing it to call "describe_workspaces" in forloop to be called >=2 times for every region? Check network elements as well and all seems fine with 200OK so I dont know what is causing so called reload.

Comment: How do you test the client-side? a browser ? did you try different browsers ?

Comment: Where is `region_endpoint_dict` coming from? And why are you writing wsgi directly, rather than using a micro framework like Flask?

Comment: @DanielRoseman : it is a legacy thing which I have to carry forward..I will use the framework in the next revision. region_endpoint_dict is a dictionary of region:endpoint

Comment: @alfasin : I tried on my dev enviornment, the function is called only once, may be it happens sometimes. I am not able to figure out a concrete reason but on prod it is certain that it is getting hit >=2. I have not tried different browser. Will update once I try it.

Comment: so chrome is THE culprit..safari seems to hit once only. I have disabled some of the chrome extensions too but no help. Also, it is submitting through GET method not POST so may be 2 request for GET and POST redirection.

Comment: @user3089927 yes that's what I suspected. I ran into the same issue with chrome in the past, you'll have to workaround it AFAIK.

Comment: so what work around can I put in..that request should not proceed if done consecutively, something like that?